# woocommerce product aligning

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: Text]

Hello, im facing some alignment problems in my site.
I want to leave images uncropped , because we have tons of images with different height and width. So we came to solution that we need only the price and titles to be aligned. Is it possible to do in woocommerce+oceanwp? it should be done with css or php?

Comment: Hi is your website live? If so, can you post a link to it? I can help you out pretty easily if you can.

Answer (score 1):

So i came up with some css which worked

```
ul.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.product .title {
    min-height: 88px;
}
ul.products li.product a h3 {
  min-height: 40px;
}
```